# SQL Server how to write query to pick the latest record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server, I have a subscription table as below. It saves all the subscription status. It creates a record when active one subscription, cancel or reactive. For example, like `Product_ID = 4`. I active the subscription on 2020-07-11 and then cancel it on 2020-09-14 and reactive on 2020-11-15.

```
Subscription_ID|Company_ID|Product_ID|Subscription_Status|    Action_Date    |
---------------|----------|----------|-------------------|-------------------| 
              1|        1 |         4|             active|2020-07-11 12:00:00| 
              2|        1 |         1|             active|2020-07-13 12:00:00| 
              3|        1 |         2|             active|2020-07-15 12:00:00|  
              4|        1 |         3|             active|2020-08-12 12:00:00|      
              5|        1 |         4|             cancel|2020-09-14 12:00:00|    
              6|        1 |         2|             cancel|2020-10-15 12:00:00|
              7|        1 |         4|             active|2020-11-15 12:00:00|
              8|        1 |         3|             cancel|2020-12-15 12:00:00|   
              9|        1 |         5|             active|2020-12-18 12:00:00|
```

How can I write a query to get all the latest rows for all products?

For example, the result I want to get is:

```
Subscription_ID|Company_ID|Product_ID|Subscription_Status|    Action_Date    |
              2|        1 |         1|             active|2020-07-13 12:00:00| 
              6|        1 |         2|             cancel|2020-10-15 12:00:00|
              7|        1 |         4|             active|2020-11-15 12:00:00|
              8|        1 |         3|             cancel|2020-12-15 12:00:00|   
              9|        1 |         5|             active|2020-12-18 12:00:00|
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`

```
select *
from (
    select t.*
        , row_number() over (partition by Product_ID order by Action_Date desc) rn
    from table_name t
) a
where a.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
select t.*
from your_table t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from your_table tt
    where tt.Company_ID = t.Company_ID and tt.product_id = t.product_id
    and tt.action_Date > t.action_date
)
```

Or you can use the analytical function `row_number` as follows:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*
        , row_number() over (partition by Company_ID,product_id 
                                order by action_date desc) as rn
    from your_table t
) t
where rn = 1
```